# argument of type "void" is incompatible error

Tags: c++, function-pointers

hello and thanks in advance for supporting,

I'm trying to send a pointer to function which is type void and receive nothing.

it didn't work well so far.

here is my minimal code that have this problem:

```
void func::foo()
{
    return;
}
```

and the function which use it is:

```
void func::create_func(void(*wanted_func)())
{
    wanted_func();
}
```

the problem is when it called:

```
create_func(foo);
```

please advice,
I hope i haven't asked something that is very silly

Comment: Is `func` a class or a namespace? If it is a class, is `foo` static?

Comment: Turning your code into a full example compiles fine: https://godbolt.org/z/zMnGoMM5Y so please provide a [mcve] that we can use to reproduce your problem.

Comment: func is a class,

Comment: I'm getting 2 errors:
argument of type "void (func::*)()" is incompatible with parameter of type "void (*)()" 
and:
'FunctionCalculator::foo': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member 
thanks for help!

Comment: You cannot take the address of a member function into a non-member function pointer, unless the member function is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you'd like to pass a member method pointer to another member method. So you'll have to bind an object instance to the method that you want to pass.
Have a look at `std::bind` ([Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind))

Here is a minimal example which I believe does what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Func {
 public:
    void foo() {
      std::cout << "called foo\n";
    }
    
    void create_func(std::function<void()> functor) {
        functor();
    }

};

int main() {
    Func f;
    f.create_func(std::bind(&Func::foo, f));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are changing the function pointer to a generic callable object (i.e. `std::function`), don't lambdas pretty much fully replace `bind`?

Comment: Yes indeed! This would also allow us to write `f.create_func([&f](){f.foo();});`